# asp.net web form textboxes with no spacing between them

Tags: css, asp.net, textbox

I have a number of rows with several textboxes, ,see image.

I want to avoid the space between each row of fields...this is what I am getting now...

[image]

I am using IE9.

I have used on CSS `margin:0` but doesn't do anything.

This is the code used (partial):

```
                  <div id="div_DEM_D" runat="server" class="DIV_detailsDEM" style="height:72px;margin-top:-3px" visible="true">

                         <asp:TextBox  runat="server" CssClass="descD"   text="value one" ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox16" runat="server" CssClass="VD"    ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox17" runat="server" CssClass="VD"    ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox  runat="server" CssClass="descD2"   text="days" ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox18" runat="server" CssClass="VD"   style="width:30px"  ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox19" runat="server" CssClass="VD"     ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox20" runat="server" cssClass="VD"    ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox  runat="server" cssClass="descD2"  text="day" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                         <asp:TextBox  runat="server" CssClass="descD"   text="value two"></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox21" runat="server" CssClass="VD"    ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox22" runat="server" CssClass="VD"     ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox  runat="server" CssClass="descD2"   text="days"></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox23" runat="server" CssClass="VD"   style="width:30px"  ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox24" runat="server" CssClass="VD"    ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox25" runat="server" cssClass="VD"     ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox  runat="server" cssClass="descD2"  text="day" ></asp:TextBox>
                        <br />
                         <asp:TextBox  runat="server" CssClass="descD"   text="value three"></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox26" runat="server" CssClass="VD"    ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox27" runat="server" CssClass="VD"     ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox  runat="server" CssClass="descD2"   text="days"></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox28" runat="server" CssClass="VD"   style="width:30px"  ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox29" runat="server" CssClass="VD"     ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox30" runat="server" cssClass="VD"    ></asp:TextBox>
                         <asp:TextBox  runat="server" cssClass="descD2"  text="day" ></asp:TextBox>
                         <br />
                     </div>
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margin:

```
margin-right: -10px;
```

This is really an HTML CSS issue, not asp.net.